# How to disable PHPSESSID on dynamic sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, session-cookies

I have detected that my server uses PHPSESSID through Google Webmaster Tools. The Bounce Rate as shown in Google Analytics started to increase from about 2 to 75% since I have detected PHPSESSID two weeks ago. With it a whole bunch of URL parameters showed up on my site. I’m unable to delete them and I can only decide if the entries have an effect on the behavior of my site or not. I can see over 160 re-directs to duplicate content. I know that I can use the following entries:

```
 php_value session.use_only_cookies 1 
 php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
```

in .htaccess to prevent PHPSESSID from appearing.

However this doesn’t solve the problem. Since I do have a dynamic site I can’t use this code:

```
$actualurl= 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$correcturl = 'http://www.ragepank.com/articles/26/disable-phpsessid/'; 
if ($correcturl != $actualurl) { 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: " . $correcturl); 
exit(); 
}
```

on every page to prevent redirecting visitors. Any ideas are appreciated.

P.S. The site runs on Apache Server.

Comment: "The Bounce Rate as shown in Google Analytics started to increase from about 2 to 75% since I have detected PHPSESSID two weeks ago." Why are you thinking a URL parameter would be causing a bounce rate?

Answer (score 1):

> The Bounce Rate from 2 to 75% since PHPSESSID

sounds odd. could be a possible script kiddie attack. no one is going to close a web page because of PHPSESSID. does it come up with PHPSESSID when you visit the website.

check out coding on those webpages also that do PHPSESSID

add to php file at top

```
<?php

    ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the condition `if ($correcturl != $actualurl)` to detect logged in users. Don't do that, just use some session variable that you set after a user logs in. Then you won't need PHPSESSID in your addresses.

After a users logs in: `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`

Your new check: `if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'])`

Comment: The URL parameters contain content not related to the website i.e.:

http://www.mydomain.com/cart/?currency=EUR&main_page=page_4
http://www.mydomain.com/cart/?currency=CAD&main_page=shippinginfo&language=en
http://www.mydomain.com/cart/?currency=AUD&main_page=shippinginfo&language=en

I do not have any shopping cart or checkout on the website.

Comment: Then I am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve. In what way the removal of PHPSESSID is breaking your code?

Comment: What about extracting everything past '?' from REQUEST_URI end adding it to `$correcturl` before redirecting?

Comment: The Google Analytics numbers are incorrect by several hundred percent (i.e. 500 hits in WP, 15 shown in Analytics), based on WordPress page views. The Bounce Rate went up from about 2 to 75 percent. Page ranks of posts and pages went down from 2 and 4 to zero. I try to eliminate incorrect redirects.

Comment: Doesn't pagerank work only for domains? WP ang DA will always have different hit counts - WP counts script executions, GA requires a fully working webbrowser.

Comment: I use the Google Analytics Plugin for WordPress.

In Google Webmaster Tools - URL parameters - I see parameters like "http://www.mydomain.com/cart/?currency=EUR&main_page=page_4" or "http://www.mydomain.com/cart/?currency=EUR&main_page=gv_faq&faq_item=4&language=en".

How do I have such parameters without having any shopping cart or currencies on my site?

I do not track campaigns, but find this kind of parameter: "utm_medium" with samples of recently crawled URLs?

Still I have the big problem with the high Bounce Rate, and no idea where it is coming from.